# Is any anagram of the empty language the same as the empty language?

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Given a regular expression **r**, **r~** contains all anagrams of r.

**L(r)** is the language accepting all words that can be constructed from **r**.

E.g. Given the language *L(r) = {dog}*, *L(r~) = {dog,god,odg,ogd,dgo,gdo}*.

---

Given **O** which contains no words, **L(O)** is the *empty language* which contains nothing.

**Question:** Is the language ***L(O) = L(O~)*** ?

Comment: This appears to be a question asking for a nuance outside the scope of what you're dealing with. If not, then you'll need to provide exact definitions of "language", "words", etc. For example, your terminology seems to equate words and languages, since you write **L(r)** where **r** is a word, and then you later write **L(O)** where **O** is a language (at least you referred to **O** as a language in your first sentence).

Answer (score 0):

Yes? If $L(O) = \{\}$, then $L(O$~$) = \{$words that are an anagram of some word w in L(O)$\} = \{$nothing because there are no words w in $L(O)\}=\{\}$.